# errors when migrate web app from Tomcat6 to WebLogic12c

Tags: java, tomcat, weblogic, migrate

I had a work to migrate the web app from Tomcat to Weblogic12 ,I made the war use all the files under Tomcat webapp folder , then copy the war to the autodeploy folder of the weblogic ,Start up the weblogic server to make the application deployed automatic .
Then the errors occured as follows:

```
<May 28, 2012 4:43:08 AM EDT> <Notice> <LoggingService> <BEA-320401> <The log file has been rotated to /opt/Corizon/CPv434_Interim/UIService/runtime/user_projects/domains/corizon/servers/AdminServer/logs/access.log00002. Log messages will continue to be logged in /opt/Corizon/CPv434_Interim/UIService/runtime/user_projects/domains/corizon/servers/AdminServer/logs/access.log.> 
<May 28, 2012 4:43:44 AM EDT> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to STANDBY.> 
<May 28, 2012 4:43:44 AM EDT> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to STARTING.> 
<May 28, 2012 4:43:49 AM EDT> <Warning> <HTTP> <BEA-101162> <User defined listener com.genient.web.ServletContextMaintenanceListener failed: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError.
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at com.genient.config.BaseConfigManager.getConfigRootPath(BaseConfigManager.java:54)
        at com.genient.config.BaseConfigManager.getSystemConfigFilenameUsingFullPath(BaseConfigManager.java:58)
        at com.genient.config.BaseConfigManager.getSystemProperties(BaseConfigManager.java:66)
        at com.genient.config.system.SystemConfigManager.initialise(SystemConfigManager.java:115)
        at com.genient.config.system.SystemConfigManager.getInstance(SystemConfigManager.java:101)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: com.genient.platform.common.IllegalStateException: Could not determine WEB-INF directory (marker URL was '/opt/Corizon/CPv434_Interim/UIService/runtime/user_projects/domains/corizon/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/_appsdir_UIService_war/e44ur4/war/WEB-INF/lib/_wl_cls_gen.jar!/classes-marker').
        at com.genient.config.ConfigHelper.<clinit>(ConfigHelper.java:31)
        at com.genient.config.BaseConfigManager.getConfigRootPath(BaseConfigManager.java:54)
        at com.genient.config.BaseConfigManager.getSystemConfigFilenameUsingFullPath(BaseConfigManager.java:58)
        at com.genient.config.BaseConfigManager.getSystemProperties(BaseConfigManager.java:66)
        at com.genient.config.system.SystemConfigManager.initialise(SystemConfigManager.java:115)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

It seems the jar in the web-inf lib folder loaded failed .
the _wl_cls_gen.jar in "/opt/Corizon/CPv434_Interim/UIService/runtime/user_projects/domains/corizon/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/_appsdir_UIService_war/e44ur4/war/WEB-INF/lib" generated when theh weblogic startup .why this jar should be generated

Anyone know the reason will be appreciate .

UPDATE (`ConfigHelper` class):

```
URL markerURL = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("classes-marker");
markerURL=JBossVFSManager.convert(markerURL);
if(markerURL!=null) {
    final String markerPath = markerURL.getPath();
    mWebInfClassesPath = markerPath.substring(0, markerPath.lastIndexOf("classes-marker"));
    if (!new File(mWebInfClassesPath).exists()) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Could not determine WEB-INF directory (marker URL was '" + markerPath + "').");
    }
    mConfigPath = mWebInfClassesPath + DEFAULTSYSTEMPROPERTIESPATH;
}
```

Comment: This is exception is actually thrown from *your* class (`com.genient.config.ConfigHelper:31`). Can you show what is there without revealing company's secrets?

Comment: This is the class com.genient.config.ConfigHelper:

Comment: Please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/10783632/edit) and the class contents there, I can't see anything.

Comment: the calss code is a little long ,I don't know how to paste here,and this class works fine in Tomcat and JBoss .So I wonder if there are some configuration for weblogic needed .
@Tomasz,could you please give me your contact (skype or MSN)?so I can show you the related classes .

Comment: Please post the code here (you can remove *commercial* secret stuff) or use Gist/pastebin/... so that others can see it.

Comment: The ConfigHelper class:
URL markerURL = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("classes-marker");
markerURL = JBossVFSManager.convert(markerURL);
if (markerURL != null) {
 final String markerPath = markerURL.getPath();
        mWebInfClassesPath = markerPath.substring(0, markerPath.lastIndexOf("classes-marker"));
    if (!new File(mWebInfClassesPath).exists()) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Could not determine WEB-INF directory (marker URL was '" + markerPath + "').");}            
   mConfigPath = mWebInfClassesPath + DEFAULTSYSTEMPROPERTIESPATH;
        }

Comment: the JBossVFSManager.convert method:
 public static URL convert(URL url)
 {// convert those url which has vfs:// protocol
 if ((url != null) && url.getProtocol().startsWith("vfs")) {
 try {final URL realURL;
 // open connection using vfs url
 final URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
 // get virtual file from connection
final VirtualFile virtualFile = 
 (VirtualFile) connection.getContent();
 // get physical path from virtual file
realURL = VFSUtils.getPhysicalURL(virtualFile);
return realURL;
} catch (IOException e) {
m_log.error("Unable to convert vfs url.", e);
}  }return url;
}

Comment: @Tomasz ,seems the code is very hard to read.

Comment: I updated your question and added formatted code. Are you sure `/opt/Corizon/CPv434_Interim/UIService/runtime/user_projects/domains/corizon/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/_appsdir_UIService_war/e44ur4/war/WEB-INF/lib/_wl_cls_gen.jar` file exists and JVM can read it?

Comment: No,actually there is no this jar in the original lib,this jar generated when the weblogic startup,this jar just contain all the files in the web-inf/classes folder ,and there are no any calsses in the folder ,all the needed classes in web-inf/lib/*.jar .